# How can you embed table output in R-Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I was working in R script using the table() command, but we have to submit our assignments as a word doc so I made a seperate Rmarkdown and copied my code over. Is there a way to get R markdown to include the table() output that is typically displayed in the console?

This is the code

```
setwd("C:/Users/romeo/OneDrive/Documents/VCU Masters Program/Fall 2023 Classes/BIOS 543")

list.files("C:/Users/romeo/OneDrive/Documents/VCU Masters Program/Fall 2023 Classes/BIOS 543")
COVID_Data <- read.csv("COVID_19_Data.csv" )

COVID_Data_Edit <- COVID_Data


str(COVID_Data_Edit)
Jurisdiction <- COVID_Data_Edit$Jurisdiction
table(Jurisdiction)

Jurisdiction_New = ifelse(grepl("Wash", Jurisdiction), "WA",
  ifelse(grepl("Ar", Jurisdiction), "AZ",
    ifelse(grepl("Cali", Jurisdiction), "CA", 
      ifelse(grepl("Ill", Jurisdiction), "IL", 
        ifelse(grepl("Mass", Jurisdiction), "MA", 
          ifelse(grepl("Mich", Jurisdiction), "MI", 
            ifelse(grepl("Jers", Jurisdiction), "NJ", 
              ifelse(grepl("York", Jurisdiction), "NY", 
                ifelse(grepl("Vir", Jurisdiction), "VA",
                  ifelse(grepl("exas", Jurisdiction), "TX", 
                    ifelse(grepl("Penn", Jurisdiction), "PA",
                      ifelse(grepl("Un", Jurisdiction), "US",
                        ifelse(grepl("U.S", Jurisdiction), "US", "FL")))))))))))))

table(Jurisdiction_New)
```

Comment: I know this is not directly related to the question, but it is too painful to imagine you hard-coding `ifelse(a, b, ifelse(c, d, ifelse(......` Please consider using `dplyr::case_when` or `case_match`

Comment: Also, please note that you have not provided a proper reproducible example, as `setwd` and `list.files` and `read.csv` all deals with local files and paths, so either replace this with reproducible data loading function calls or remove these steps altogether if loading the data is irrelevant to the question

Comment: Code used for iteractive analysis is also useless inside the body of a question. This includes all calls to `print`, `str`, `list.files` and `table`, in the current form.

Comment: This is not a good reproducible question. You can greatly increase your chances of getting good and helpful answers if you follow some stack overflow guidelines. I strongly recommend reading these two questions and answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try the [kable](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/knitr/versions/1.43/topics/kable) function from the knitr library.

```
library(knitr)
kable(Jurisdiction_New)
```